# Determine Registration way

Tags: register

How to determine whether user has registered from dedicated registration page or from checkout registration page?

When user registers through dedicated registration page customer gets registration sms but when registers while checkout sms does not goes.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you'll need to create a module. Use the following steps:

1. Your module will contain an install script. This script will be responsible with creating a table(let's call it `registered_from` with `registered_id`, `customer_id`, `registered_from`) + creating a FK between this table and `customer_entity` table.

2.On `customer_login` event, check if the previous page was checkout page or registration page and save that information in the `registered_from` table.

3.Now, you'll be able to check if the user has been registered from checkout or from register page by checking `registered_from` value from corresponding record(loaded by `customer_id`).

Good luck !